# Reverse engineer existing database using EntityFramework.CodeTemplates gives error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to customise how a database is imported using [Code First to an Existing Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj200620) and I followed the [procedure for installing the transform templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn753860) found in the Entity Framework documentation. However when I do this I get an error (see image)

[image]

I have tried a few things and I can confirm it is about having the the  Context.cs.T4 or the EntityType.cs.T4 as part of the project. I would appreciate help as I'm stuck on this.

Notes:

- Using Visual Studio 2013
- EntityFramework 6.1.1
- EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp 6.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! I had [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj593170) installed and that caused the problem. Pity to lose that useful tool, but I just disabled it so can turn it back on when I need it.

Hope this helps someone else as that was difficult to find.